# Resize image while uploading PHP

Tags: php, image

I am uploading image with form like this:

```
include 'extraphp/config.php';

$title = $_POST['titleStory'];
$excerpt = $_POST['excerptStory'];
$story = $_POST['storyStory'];
$catagory = $_POST['catagory'];
$tags = $_POST['tagsStory'];
$author = $_POST['authorStory'];
$date = $_POST['dateStory'];

/* Image Upload */

$image = $_FILES["imageStory"];
$image2= preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $image["name"]);

$target_dir = "../uploads/large/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $image2;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageStory']['tmp_name'], $target_file);

$catagory2 = implode (", ", $catagory);
$author2 = implode(',', $author);

$sql="INSERT INTO story (titleStory,excerptStory,storyStory,catagory,tagsStory,authorStory,dateStory,imageStory) VALUES ('". $title ."','". $excerpt ."','". $story ."','". $catagory2 ."','". $tags ."','". $author2 ."','". $date ."','". $target_file ."')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
header("location: dashboard.php")
```

now I want to resize this image to 180px X 109px.
Any body help me?

Comment: You want to use the gd image library: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: When you did a Google search for "PHP resize image", did you find anything?

Comment: try http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.html or http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html

these both have code with example.

Comment: Yes I search for that but didn't get any thing, cause I am newby in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you need to check the image extension in order to use the corret `imagecreate...` funtion. The example is using always `imagecreatefromjpeg()` assuming that all uploaded images are JPG.

```
list( $imageWidth, $imageHeight ) = getimagesize( $target_file );

$resampledImage = imagecreatetruecolor( 180, 109 );

//Check file extension here to use the correct image create function
//imagecreatefromjpeg(); imagecreatefrompng(); imagecreatefromgif() etc...
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg( $target_file );

imagecopyresized( $resampledImage, $source, 180, 109, $imageWidth, $imageHeight );

ob_start();

//Check file extension here to use the correct image output function
//imagejpeg(); imagegif(); imagepng() etc...
imagejpeg( $resampledImage, null, 100 );

$imageContent = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents( $target_file, $imageContent );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: can you please put that code in my code like marge both code?

Comment: Just paste it under `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageStory']['tmp_name'], $target_file);`

Comment: And the other one which I upload is not present (means not upload) in folder. I need both the large one (which I uploaded and that which is resize by the script)

Comment: Just study `file_put_contents()` function docs. The first parameter will be the destination of the resampled image. The code is using the same path as the original file previously uploaded, you just alter it to whatever you want.